# Loop in which Scanner does not fetch input

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

Im having a problem creating an error message in my distance to origin calculator program.

```
double x;                                 // x coordinate
double y;                                 // y coordinate
String quadrant;                          //new string: quadrant

System.out.println("Enter x coordinate");//prompt user to enter x coordinate

do{System.out.println ("Error: Enter a number");}while (!input.hasNextDouble());  

x = input.nextDouble()+.0;
```

When I run the program I get an error message directly after the prompt for the value.  If I type in an invalid character it starts an infinite loop with the error.  If I move the do-while loop to after the `input.nextdouble` it does nothing.

complete code:

```
package distancefromorigin;
/**
 * Distance from origin calculator application
 * Created for CSCI 11
 * Last modified 9/22/2013 2:30 AM
 * @author Steve Pesce
 */
import java.util.Scanner;                           //Start Scanner utility

public class DistanceFromOrigin 
{
    public enum Quad    //initialize enum Quad with values 1-4 in roman numerals

    {I , II, III, IV}


/**
 * main method calculates distance from a point to
 * the origin using the Cartesian coordinate system
 * and locates the quadrant that the point lies in
 */    


    public static void main(String[] args) 
      {

       Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);  // new scanner (imput)

       Quad loc;                                 //new Quad : loc (quadrant #)

       double dist;                              //distance from (x,y) to (0,0)

       double x;                                 // x coordinate

       double y;                                 // y coordinate

       String quadrant;                          //new string: quadrant


       System.out.println("Enter x coordinate");//prompt user to enter x coordinate






       x = input.nextDouble()+.0;           //save next number entered as x

       do 
       {
           System.out.println ("Error: Enter a number");

       }while (!input.hasNextDouble());  

       System.out.println("Enter y coordinate"); 

       do 
       {
           System.out.println ("Error: Enter a number");
       }
       while (!input.hasNextDouble()); 


       //prompt user to enter y coordinate
       y = input.nextDouble()+ .0;          //save next number entered as y 


       if (x == 0)                                    //if x=0 and y doesn't = 0
       {    

          if (y >= 0)                   //and if y greater than or equal to zero
          {                
              dist = y;                                     //then distance is y
          }

          else                                                //if y is negative
          {    
               dist = -y ;                              //then distance is y(-1)
          }
       }                

       else if ((y == 0) && (x != 0))                // if y=0 and x doesn't = 0
       {
           if (x > 0)                                    // and if x is positive

           {
                   dist = x ;                              // then distance is x
           }

           else                                              // if x is negative 
           {
                       dist = -x ;                     // then distance is x(-1)
           }

       }   

       //if x and y both don't equal zero then use hypotenuse formula
      else dist = (Math.hypot ((double) x , (double) y));  


       if (x >= 0)            //if x is non negative
       {
           if (y < 0)         //and if y is negative 
           { 
               loc = Quad.IV;//then point is in quadrant IV
           }
           else loc = Quad.I;//if x and y are both nonnegative then the point
       }                     //is in quadrant I
       else if (y < 0)       //if x is negative and y is negative
       {                     
           loc = Quad.III;  //then the point is in quadrant III
       }
       else loc = Quad.II;  //if x is negative and y is nonnegative then the
                            //point is in quadrant II




       //Print "the point (x,y) is (dist) units away from the origin (0,0) 
       // and is in quadrant (loc)"
            System.out.println( "The point("
                    + (int)x + "," + (int)y + ") is " + (double)dist
                    +" units from the origin (0,0) and is in Quadrant " +
                                loc + ".");








}//end main()
}//end class DistanceFromOrigin
```

Comment: It's Java.and this comment is long enough.

Comment: `Scanner`s and `System.out` are Java things.

Comment: You never actually clear any invalid input. That's why it infinite loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run

```
do{
     System.out.println ("Error: Enter a number");
}while (!input.hasNextDouble());
```

The `input.hasNextDouble()` checks whether there is a `double` waiting at the command line. If you instead get a string with `input.next()` and check each time whether it is a dobule, the program will wait appropriately.

You can instead do

```
double double1=-1;
while (double1!=-1){
     String number=input.next();
     try{
         double1=Double.parseDouble(number);
     }catch(NumberFormatException e){
       //that wasn't proper input.
         System.out.println ("Error: Enter a number");

     }
}
```

Look at the [Double](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) and [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) classes for more information.

Comment: OK thanks. I think i may be trying to do something more advanced than what i have learned so far.

Comment: try parsing a file full of numbers instead, that way you don't have to wait for user input, or else assume that the user has entered the data correctly and don't try to validate it.

Comment: It's much easier to check wether a string is a double by just catching the exception thrown when you try to parse it, then you also have x parsed when you leave the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your do-while loop is structured correctly. It gives the error message 100% of the time.

Try something like:

> while(true){
>
> ```
> String temp = input.next();    //get next token of input
> try{
>
> x = Double.parseDouble(temp);       //try to parse a double
>
> break;                              //break out of the loop if double was parsed
>
> }catch(NumberFormatException e){    //if the token isnt a double, handle exception
>
> System.out.println("Error message");
>
> }
>
> }
> ```